# tomcat 8 suddenly not respond

Tags: java, tomcat

I have web application on tomcat8, which has jsp and servlets, this is primarily used by an legacy system(not used by user) to get records from DB. I faced an peculiar issue, after couple of month of deployment, it suddenly stopped responding to request and no logs printed until tomcat was restarted. when checked logs that was printed before issue, I saw below lines,

> 0.10.0.27 - - [**31/Dec/1969:18:59:59 -0500**] "-" 200 -
>
> 0.10.0.27 - - [**31/Dec/1969:18:59:59 -0500**] "-" 200 -

Please check the date, it looks weird.

I didn't find any OutofMemory errors or any DB connect exceptions. Since the server was handled by other team, I was not able to check CPU and RAM usages before tomcat restart.

**Environment details below,**

Apache Tomcat/8.0.52

Windows Server 2012 R2(64 bit)

Java 1.8.0_171-b11(server JRE)

Xenon 4 core CPU

RAM 2GB

I know the information provided is little, but I just want to know if anybody else faced similar issue.

Comment: Its very hard to say, with such little information.But usually if you have problem like this the admin guys, should usually do the jstack(list of all threads state), they should collect at least gc logs, and if the application is really stuck they should also create headdump. This is good start for the analysis. Without these information you are completely blind and everybody can only guess what happens.

Comment: Have you checked the system  clock on the server? What does it display now? Are the times in the logs up to date now?

Comment: all the localhost access log seems to be printing right date and time, these two logs were found different

Comment: Without any thread-dump or error logs configured with the right level, we can't guess nothing.